# How to access and change(class) __init__ method attributes from another function in python?

Tags: python

Recently I was trying to access an `__init__` method attribute to change its values and recalculate some properties automatically from another function.

I have tried some basic approaches and did not succeed to obtain what I wanted. This is the code in question:

```
class Square():
     def __init__(self, length, width):
         self.length = length
         self.width = width

     @property
     def Area(self):
         return self.length * self.width

A1 = Square(length=3, width=3) ## made an object
print(A1.Area) #9

def check():
    a = []
    b = [1,3,2]
    t = [100,20,23]
    d = [0.1]
    c = 4
    for i in d:
        c += 6
        d += [0.1]
        if A1.Area < 8: ## eg. if A1.length=2 and A1.width=2 have been changed in the  __init__ attribute this A1.Area would be 4 and the condtion is ture and the loop break ends
            break ## here break the loop finally  if the A1.Area is altered by the conditions 
        for k in range(len(b)):
            a.append(c + b[k])
            if c + b[k] > t[2]:
                A1.length = 2## here i am trying to change the __init__ attribute
                A1.width = 2 ## here i am trying to change the __init__ attribute
                print(k)
                c = c - 6
                break
    return c
```

Comment: what do you mean? A1=Square(length=3,width=3) i defined the Square instances not the Square attribute?

Comment: What is the exact problem ? You can't change `length` and `width` ?

Comment: yes from the function ''check'' by the outcome of the conditions. Dimitri Mockelyn

Comment: Well, you had it right. That's the way you change an attribute. You should check whether you enter this if loop or not. If `A1` never changes, my guess would be that you never have `c+b[k]>t[2]`

Comment: If it's a **Square** - why does it need a *length* **and** a *width* ?

Comment: Dimitri Mockelyn true, but the loop passed the if condition and it was running infinitely. i just dont know how to acccess a the attribute of the __init__ from another function.

Comment: @Jack if it's meant to be a rectangle - name it `Rectangle` :)

Comment: The code you've show works for me. It prints `1` and returns `22`. You don't say what you expect the code to do (and it's by no means obvious by looking at it), so I can't tell if this is the answer you want. `A1`'s `width` and `length` attributes do get updated (at the same time the `print` happens).

Comment: yes i want it to print 22 how did you do it? so it updated? strange i will have to look at my code again may be indentation error. but thanks, Blcknght

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really are trying to do in your check function but the following works ok for me:

```
>>> class Square():
...      def __init__(self,length, width):
...          self.length=length
...          self.width=width
...      @property
...      def area(self):
...          return(self.length*self.width)
...
>>> a=Square(2,3)
>>> a.length
2
>>> a.area
6
>>> a.length=4
>>> a.length
4
>>> a.area
12
>>> for i in range(4):
...   a.length = i
...   print a.area
...
0
3
6
9
```

Comment: i know this works but i am trying to alter the outcome of class, by function 'check' output.

Comment: Well, the title of your question mislead me, and I find the content not clear. Could you provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @jack Whether you do that "directly" or from within a function, it should make no difference.